# PrimaryGeneratedColumn needs to be unique

Tags: postgresql, orm, nestjs, typeorm

So I wanted to implement that when a `GraphNode` gets deleted, and the `id` of the `GraphNode` is the `startNodeId`, then this will be resetted to `null`.
So I came up with the following:

Graph:

```
@Entity()
export class Graph extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public startNodeId?: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => GraphNode, { onDelete: 'SET NULL' })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'startNodeId', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  public startNode: GraphNode;
}
```

GraphNode:

```
@Entity()
export class GraphNode extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  public id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn('uuid')
  public graphId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Graph)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'graphId' })
  public graph: Graph;
}
```

Error:
`No unique Unique-Constraint in the referenced table graphNode`

So if I now add `@Unique(['id'])` to the `GraphNode`, it works. But the `id` already has the `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` decorator. Is it necessary for that use-case to define an `id` as unique?

Comment: You are creating a FK to your referencedColumnName. A FK can only reference a primary or unique key - so yes id would need to be unique. However there is an alternative: reference the primary key.  Also I don't know how your ORM handles uuid, but in Postgres itself uuid is a valid data type, which would be preferred over text for processing them.

Comment: Isn't a `PrimaryGeneratedColumn` a primary column?

Comment: The PK would be referenced as any other column. It is the designation of being the primary key that makes it unique and therefore can be referenced from other tables.